How to add Kafka retries topics configuration
I set up message sending with exponential retries via kafka with spring-kafka (3.0.13). My main topics are created via KafkaAdmin using TopicBuilder:
@PostConstruct
    fun initTopics() {
        topics.map {
            TopicBuilder
                .name(it)
                .replicas(replicationFactor)
                .partitions(partition)
                .configs(mapOf(
                    TopicConfig.MIN_IN_SYNC_REPLICAS_CONFIG to minInsyncReplicas.toString(),
                    TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG to retentionMs.toString()
                ))
                .build()
        }.apply {
            kafkaAdmin.createOrModifyTopics(*toTypedArray())
        }
    }

retry topics are created by the retry configuration:
@Bean
    fun retryTopicConfiguration() = RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
        .newInstance()
        .autoCreateTopics(true, partition, replicationFactor.toShort())
        .maxAttempts(attempts)
        .exponentialBackoff(initialInterval, multiplier, maxInterval)
        .sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy(SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
        .includeTopics(topics)
        .retryOn(KafkaRetryableException::class.java)
        .dltProcessingFailureStrategy(DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR)
        .dltHandlerMethod(EndpointHandlerMethod(KafkaDltHandler::class.java, "dlt"))
        .create(kafkaTemplate)

The problem is that I cannot add a config for the MIN_IN_SYNC_REPLICAS_CONFIG and RETENTION_MS_CONFIG properties as for the creation of the main topics. Consequently, the retry and dlt topics are not configured like the main topics. I don't understand why it's not possible to add a config with RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder so I'm wondering if I'm missing something?
